# Debugging huge memory allocation occurring before identified problematic function

Tags: org-mode, debugging, edebug

I identified a particular situation which causes emacs allocates infinitely memory (and then freezes my PC).

To be specific, I have an external link `[[file:article.djvu::5][problematic djvu file]]` in an org-mode buffer. Calling <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-html-export-to-html` freezes my PC.

The file must be a `.djvu` and the `::5` in the link is necessary, otherwise `org-html-export-to-html` works as expected. I also tried to only load relevant libraries (in my view) such as `org-mode`, `pdf-tools` and `org-pdftools`, but no freeze occurred. So I'm debugging with my full configuration.

Now, as I know that `org-html-export-to-html` causes the issue, I use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `debug-on-entry` to that function. However, the freeze occurs before the breakpoint reached.

Since the freeze occurred between calling <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-html-export-to-html` and the entry to it, I don't know how to track this issue step-by-step.

It's possible to use `edebug` to start debugging as soon as I press <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-html-export-to-html`? Since the issue is very specific, I'm looking for help on the debug process but not the issue itself.

**UPDATE**:

I got some progress on the issue. Lately, I've tried to <kbd>M-x</kbd> `edebug-on-entry` to `counsel-M-x` but it doesn't work. I disabled `ivy` and <kbd>M-x</kbd> `debug-on-entry` to `execute-extended-command` (a.k.a <kbd>M-x</kbd>). What happens now is that in the below backtrace, as soon as I pressed <kbd>d</kbd> (step through), the debugger doesn't step forward
and starting allocate infinitely memory.

```
Debugger entered--entering a function:
* command-execute(org-html-export-to-html record)
* #f(compiled-function (prefixarg &optional command-name typed) "Read a command name, then read the arguments and call the command.\nTo pass a prefix argument to the command you are\ninvoking, give a prefix argument to `execute-extended-command'." (interactive #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x20c5849>)) #<bytecode 0x1cb743>)(nil "org-html-export-to-html" "org-html-ex-to-html")
* apply(#f(compiled-function (prefixarg &optional command-name typed) "Read a command name, then read the arguments and call the command.\nTo pass a prefix argument to the command you are\ninvoking, give a prefix argument to `execute-extended-command'." (interactive #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x2151b59>)) #<bytecode 0x1cb743>) (nil "org-html-export-to-html" "org-html-ex-to-html"))
* execute-extended-command(nil "org-html-export-to-html" "org-html-ex-to-html")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "org-html-export-to-html" "org-html-ex-to-html")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Comment: What kind of freeze? Do you have to reboot, restart emacs, or will `C-g` get you out of it? How do you know that emacs allocates "infinite" memory"?

Comment: @NickD Complete freeze, i.e. `C-g` doesn't work at all. I monitor memory usage with `htop` and within 5 seconds `emacs` allocates 12+ Gb of RAM. I kill `emacs` in time before the OS do it.